# My orginal data set of actual and predicted has over 5000+ values i want to only plot 150 values

Tags: python, matplotlib, regression, jupyter

I tried the below code but it didn't work what else should i try

```
 fig=plt.figure()
    plt.plot(ypredicted[0:150],color="red",linewidth=2.5,linestyle="-")
    plt.plot(actual[0:150],color="blue",linewidth=2.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this because it is a line chart and all of those points are connected. I'm assuming you want a scatter plot showing the predicted on x-axis and actual on y-axis. If they have a positive relationship, then you know that the model is more or less predicting okay.

Try replacing your plt.plot lines with

plt.scatter(ypredicted[0:150], actual[0:150])

plt.show()

Comment: thnaks and how do i assign different colors to ypredicted and actual in scatterplot?

Comment: You only have one point, so there is not a separate point for your actual and predicted values.